# geom_rect() error: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function"

Tags: r

When I run the simple code:

```
dataset1 = data.frame(xvar = 1:100, yvar=100:1)
dataset2 = data.frame(group_start = 1:5,
                      group_end = 2:6,
                      startval= c(4,9,15,36,50),
                      endval = c(9,15,36,50,100))

ggplot(dataset1, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(data = dataset2,
        mapping = aes(xmin = startval, xmax = endval,
                      ymin = group_start, ymax = group_end,
                      fill=t),
        color="black",
        alpha=0.5,
        inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

I get the error

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function.    
Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0
```

I was wondering what this means and how it can be solved.

Given the `object of type function` part of the message I checked whether any of my column names are built-in functions. The answer is no.

I further checked whether it has anything to do with the different columns in the different datasets being of a different data type. When I change all columns to `numeric` the problem remains.

Comment: What's up with `fill=t`? What are you trying to do there? You don't seem to have a column named "t" and `t()` happens to be the base function to transpose a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `fill=t` to `fill=as.factor(group_start)` or something